# how can I tail a file with a dynamic grep pattern?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, tail

I have a log file containing lines about different users, and I'm tailing this file in real time. I want to filter out the lines that are only related to a user that I specify, ex: 1234. The log entries look like this:

```
ID:101 Username=1234
ID:102 Username=1234
ID:999 UNWANTED LINE (because this ID was not assigned to user 1234)
ID:102 some log entry regarding the same user
ID:123 UNWANTED LINE (because this ID was not assigned to user 1234)
ID:102 some other text
ID:103 Username=1234
ID:103 blablabla
```

A dynamic ID is assigned to a user in a line like "ID:101 Username=1234". Any subsequent lines that start with that ID pertain to the same user and will need to be displayed. I need a dynamic tail that would get all IDs related to the specified user (1234) and filter the previous lines as follows:

```
ID:101 Username=1234
ID:102 Username=1234
ID:102 some log entry regarding the same user
ID:102 some other text
ID:103 Username=1234
ID:103 blablabla
```

I need to first filter the lines where "Username=1234" is found, then extract the "ID:???" from that line, then tail all lines that contain "ID:???". When another line with "Username=1234" is found, extract the new ID and use it to display the subsequent lines with this new ID.

I am able to chain greps to filter out the ID when I use cat, but it doesn't work when I chain them after a tail. But even if I could, how do I "watch" for a new value of ID and dynamically update my grep pattern???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a task that Awk can handle with ease (and it could be handled with Perl or Python too).

```
awk '$2 == "Username=1234" { ids[$1]++; } $1 in ids  { print }' data
```

The first pattern/action pair records the `ID:xxx` value for an entry where `$2` is `Username=1234` in the array `ids`.  The second pattern/action pair looks whether the `ID:xxx` entry is listed in `ids`; if so, it prints the line.  The `Username=1234` lines satisfy both criteria (at least, after the entry is added to the array).

> How do I use it so it can act like `tail` (i.e. print the new lines as they're added to data)?

```
tail -f logfile | awk …
```

You'd miss the name of the data file from the `awk` part of the command, of course.  The only thing you'd have to watch for is that tail doesn't hang-up waiting to fill the pipe buffer.  It probably won't be a problem, but you might have to look hard at the options to `tail` if it takes longer for lines to appear in the Awk input than you expected.

> I realized that ID:XXX doesn't necessarily always come at position $1... is there a way to match the ID with a regular expression regardless of its position in the line ($1, $2, ...)?

Yes:

```
awk '$2 == "Username=1234" { ids[$1]++; }
     { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i in ids) { print; break }' data
```

The second line matches every line, and for each field in the line, checks whether that field is present in `ids` array.  If it is, it prints the line and breaks out of the loop (you could use `next` instead of `break` in this context, though the two are not equivalent in general).

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!! But how do I use it so it can act like tail (i.e. print the new lines as they're added to data?).

Comment: Use `tail -f logfile | awk …` to continue reading indefinitely.

Comment: Man you're awesome!! That's exactly it!! just one last thing... I realized that ID:XXX doesn't necessarily always come at position $1... is there a way to match the ID with a regular expression regardless of its position in the line ($1, $2, ...)?

Comment: I  recently encountered a `programthatneverexits | awk` command line, and the main problem is: if `awk` does buffered reads from pipes, you might not see output all that promptly. This doesn't seem to be an issue for `gawk`, but for `mawk`, which is the default awk on some distros, it helps to add the `-W interactive` option, so that it uses unbuffered reads